# How to save all pages of a Word document as image?

Tags: c#, image, ms-word

I try to save all pages of a Word document as an Enhanced Metafile (.emf) image using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WordToImg
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Doc|*.doc;*.docx";
            ofd.Title = "Select file to convert";
            ofd.InitialDirectory=Application.StartupPath;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = ofd.FileName;
                word.Application app = new word.Application();
                word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(file);

                byte[] bytes = (byte[])app.ActiveDocument.Content.EnhMetaFileBits;
                if (bytes != null)
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    Image temp = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    temp.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(file) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                doc.Close(false);
                doc = null;
                app.Quit();
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the created metafile only contains the contents of the first page. Is there a way to get the entire document contents as image? Or, maybe, get the contents of each page separately using `Content.EnhMetaFileBits`?

Comment: Why are there so many `ref objectMissing`s?

Comment: This code is not mine, It's for example. I don't use 'ref objectMissing'

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_. It's not enough to just show us the code you copied from somewhere. What did you attempt in order to achieve your goals?

Comment: Wow, relax, I tried to save doc to image, but 'Content.EnhMetaFileBits;' returns bytes of first doc's page but I need to save all doc as image(s)

Comment: Your code doesn't even show what `EnhMetaFileBits` is, because we don't know what's the type of `wordApp`, what library your using, etc.

Comment: I embeded my code to the question, EnhMetaFileBits is array of bits of MemoryStrem. Library is Microsoft's intercrop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
 byte[] bytes = (byte[])app.ActiveDocument.Content.EnhMetaFileBits;
```

To:

```
 byte[] bytes = (byte[])app.ActiveDocument.Range().EnhMetaFileBits;
```